# How do I count the occurence of an integer in a list and output it correctly?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

To start, I'm new to Java and I just started learning it around a month ago.

One of my HW Questions is "Write a program that prompts the user for a positive
number N, followed by a list of positive numbers. The user indicates the end of the
list with -1. The program will then output the number of occurrence of N is the list"

Currently, my program doesn't end when I input -1 in the list. I'm so confused because every tutorial I see online involves arrays, which I haven't learnt yet.

```java
public class CountOccurence {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a list of positive numbers\nEnter -1 to indicate end:");
        int count = 0;
        int input;
        while (num1 > 0) {
            sc.nextInt();
            input = sc.nextInt();
            while (input == num1) {
                int count2 = count + 1;
                while (input == -1) {
                    System.out.println("Your number occurs" + count2 + "times");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `num1 ` is not getting a new value within your loop

Comment: What is the purpose of `sc.nextInt();` without assigning return value to a variable?

Comment: Also `sc.nextInt();
                  input = sc.nextInt();` - why?

Comment: @ScaryWombat
That was unintended, sorry.

Comment: @Andreas That was unintended, sorry.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do you know how to let the user input a list of numbers that terminates? My program is letting them input the list but it doesn't end when the input is -1. I think that's the main problem I'm facing but I can't seem to wrap my head around it

Comment: See my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you haven't learned about arrays, the idea behind your solution is quite ingenious, but there are some mistakes that would render your code dysfunctional.

First off, there are many `while` loops that would either not execute or loop infinitely. It appears that you've mixed up `while` loops with `if` statements. You can read more about the difference [here](https://www.quora.com/WHat-is-the-difference-between-an-if-and-a-while-loop).

As both Andreas and Scary Wombat pointed out, there's a straggling `sc.nextInt();` that isn't assigned to anything. Delete that, since it will unintentionally drop inputs from the user.

With that in mind, here's my solution using your method.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountOccurence {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a list of positive numbers\nEnter -1 to indicate end:");
        int count = 0;
        int input = 0;
        while (input != -1) {
            input = sc.nextInt();
            if (input == num1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your number occurs " + count + " times");
    }
}
```

I chose to print the occurances at the very end, since that's after the user types `-1`.

By the way, welcome to the Stack Overflow community!

Comment: I just realized how much more efficient it is to use (input != -1) instead of whatever I was doing. Btw thanks for the help and the welcome!

Comment: Thanks, @HassanHaroon! If you found my answer helpful, then please mark it as the accepted answer.